# how to search in a list in java?

Tags: java, list, search

i have three list containing 3/4 items in each. Now a node contains each those items. when the node is assigned to a particular item it has to search for that item in those list and should return the particular list containing that item. How can i do this?

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: Did you try .contains() ?

Comment: Show us what you tried, what worked and what didn't. Give us error messages and we'll try and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : 
In case the

```
if(listOne.contains(object))
            return listOne;
```

The list.contains() uses equals. so, if list.contains() does not give you the expected result, you should be overriding the equals method.